# Dapper.net transaction problem

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, orm, dapper

I'm trying to commit a transaction to my Sql Server 2008 database - firstly 2 insert's followed by a couple update's, however, as soon as it attempts to execute the first of the update's, I get the following error:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the
>   connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. 
>   The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

Here's the code, edited slightly for brevity:

```
using (_cn)
{
    _cn.Open();
    IDbTransaction transaction = _cn.BeginTransaction();
    topicId = (int)_cn.Query<decimal>(qAddTopic, new { pForumId = topic.ForumId }, transaction).Single();
    postId = (int)_cn.Query<decimal>(qAddPost, new { pTopicId = topicId }, transaction).Single();

    _cn.Execute(qUpdateForums, new { pLastPostId = postId });
    _cn.Execute((qUpdateSiteTotals));

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

The first 2 inserts work fine, but as soon as it tries to perform one of the updates, no joy.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have found the problem - I was simply missing the transaction param when I was calling the updates, whereas with the previous inserts that were working fine, I had included the `IDbTransaction` param! My bad!

Example:

```
Connection.Query<Entitiy>("sqlQuery",param: new { id= ID}, transaction: Transaction)
```

Comment: `Connection.Query<Entitiy>("sqlQuery",param: new { id= ID}, transaction: Transaction)`

Comment: If your query isn't using any parameters (say, `select * from table`), if you just pass the `transaction` dapper will interpret it as a parameter object. So the above syntax using named optional parameters will prevent that.

Comment: I had used commandDefinition, so used the below.

`CommandDefinition command = new CommandDefinition(storedProcedureName, dynamicParameters,
                commandTimeout: commandTimeout, commandType: commandType, transaction: _dbTransaction);`

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft recommends to use `TransactionScope` over database `IDbTransaction` when possible. The following code should work, assuming that nothing's wrong with your SQL and the managed provider automatically enlists in the ambient transaction - something that well-behaved providers need to do.

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
  using (_cn)
  {
    _cn.Open();
    ...
  }
  
  ts.complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Oliver. Unfortunately it looks like Dapper.net doesn't support TransactionScope, just IDbTransaction :(

Comment: @marcusstarnes are you sure? its supposed to work. Just dont use BeginTransaction and Commit. transactionScope will handle rest

Comment: Dapper is absolutely agnostic to transactions. I'm using TransactionScope in conjunction with Dapper with absolutely zero problems.

Comment: That's because TransactionScope, by design, affects all connections automatically. It's not that Dapper has something specific to transactions.

Comment: This brings errors of its own when using with dapper - Enlisting in Ambient transactions is not supported (feb 2019).

Comment: This should work in .NET Framework, but won't work in .NET Core until there is a resolution to https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/715

Comment: transactionScope is distributed and therefore configuring them when the database is not on the same server is quite a handful. I understand is for distributed transactions

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the problem was in my case. I had this code and it all looked fine.

```
public async Task ClearCurrentBasePriceFile(IDbTransaction transaction = null)
{
    var connection = transaction?.Connection ?? _db;

    await connection.ExecuteAsync(@"
        DELETE
        FROM PRICE_LIST_BASE",
        transaction
    ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I am passing in the transaction. I am certain the transaction is not null. But it would still give me the error.

Turns out, if I add `null` in front of the `transaction` parameter, where the `param` parameter should be, then it works. It seems that it was taking the transaction parameter as the param parameter and hence it was thinking that I was not supplying the transaction.